# How to create readonly textbox-like structure using html (div/span) and css?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with a read-only text box which shows some HTML code:

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" value="<table>...</table>"/>
```

There is also submit button, which causes page post back and XSS validation to trigger. I don't want to turn off XSS.

I also tried disabled="disabled", but then the user is not able to copy the text in the text box.

So I thought that using div and span which can give same look and feel would suffice and negate the need for turning off the validation.  While trying this, I am struggling to restrict the string in one line. As in text box, it is a single row with column size and text is shown nicely, we can also copy text.

Is there a better solution for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to show some example code in a web interface that is formatted for easy consumption by the end user.

As a general rule, you should wrap code snippets in  `<pre></pre>` tags, I would then suggest having a go at using: http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter to format the code as if you were viewing in an IDE.

This will prevent you from having to turn of the XSS checker.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `<pre>` tags

check this [link](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/10/html-css-trick-for-displaying-code.html)